When making a server copy, 'git remote show hub' returns with HEAD: (unknown)
I am using Sourcetree and PuTTY to try to make a server copy (according to this guide).
I have triple checked that all links are correct, all spelling is correct, and that the two empty and initialized repos, site_hub.git + www, read "ref: refs/heads/master" when using cat HEADS. Sourcetree did not show any errors. However, whenever I attempt to use "git remote show hub" (after adding git remote add hub ../site_hub.git)... this is the following output:
git remote show hub
* remote hub
  Fetch URL: ../site_hub.git
  Push  URL: ../site_hub.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
  Remote branch:
    main new (next fetch will store in remotes/hub)


git branch returns no result,and git status returns
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)


I've tried creating a new branch, but it seems like I need to be pulling one from Sourcetree so I can have the files copied over?
Essentially, I'm trying to clone the origin to my own git, site_hub.git.. if I'm understanding this guide correctly.
Instead, I'm seeing the error of HEADS:(unknown).
Edit:
    [server]$ mkdir www
    [server]$ cd www
    [server]$ git init
    Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/site.com/www/.git/
    [server]$ git branch
    [server]$ git status
    On branch master
    
    No commits yet
    
    nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
    [server]$ touch init.txt
    [server]$ git add init.txt
    [server]$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
    [master (root-commit) 5f1b307] Initial Commit
     1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
     create mode 100644 init.txt
    [server]$ git remote add hub ../site_hub.git
    [server]$ git remote show hub
    * remote hub
      Fetch URL: ../site_hub.git
      Push  URL: ../site_hub.git
      HEAD branch: (unknown)
      Remote branch:
        main new (next fetch will store in remotes/hub)
    [server]$ git fetch hub
    remote: Enumerating objects: 12921, done.
    remote: Counting objects: 100% (12921/12921), done.
    remote: fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
    error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
    fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
    remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
    fatal: protocol error: bad pack header


I'm assuming I need to reset the whole process at this point..?

If I understand correctly: your repo is 100% empty. Create and push your first commit, this will actually create the master branch.

@LeGEC even then, it doesn't work. I verified this time at least, that site_hub.git has the main branch. But for some reason, www is unable to identify a HEAD.

run git push hub master : you added the correct fist steps, you are simply missing the one where you create the remote branch
